# dynamic twitter bootstrap accordion

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I would like for my twitter bootstrap accordion to put certain items together in the same accordion panel. I mean instead of it being shown as:

- commentA

  - subcommentA
- commentB

  - subcommentB
- commentA

  - subcommentC

I would like it to be shown as

- commentA

  - subCommentA
  - subcommentC
- commentB

  - subcommentB

I have been trying to do this dynamically with php/mysql but I get the first example and not the second. I have attached my code below.

```
function printSubComments(){
       $currAd = new userAds();
       $currAdImages = new images();
       $ad_id = $currAdId = $_GET['id'];
       $user_id = $currAd ->getUserIdByAdId($ad_id);
       echo'<center><h4>Further comments about this user:</h4></center>';
       $queryComment = mysql_query("SELECT visitor_comment FROM user_connection WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND visitor_vote='1'") or die(mysql_error());
       $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryComment);
       $comment = $data['visitor_comment'];
       $rows = mysql_num_rows($queryComment);

       if($rows != 0){
         echo
         '
           <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
         ';
              $i = 0; $j = 0;
              while($i < $rows){
              $querySubComment = mysql_query("SELECT visitor_sub_comment FROM user_connection WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND visitor_comment='$comment'") or die(mysql_error());
                  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($querySubComment);
              $subComment = $data['visitor_sub_comment'];
                  echo
                  '
                     <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
               <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse'.$i.'">
                  '.$comment.'
               </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse'.$i.'" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                   <ul id="subComments">
                   <li>'.$subComment.'</li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                 </div>
                  ';
                  $i++;
              }

         echo
         '     
           </div>
         ';
       }else{
         echo'<center><h5>No comment about this user at this point.</h5></center>';
       }
    }
```

I was thinking that maybe I should do a second while loop once I queryed the database for subcomments associated with any given comment but that slowly me server down. Then I thought what if I did strcmp compare each comment associated with each subcomment and add it to an array of some kind. That seemed way too complicated and unnessecary. Any help would be appreciated.